# How can I add a marker to a donut chart created with Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, donut-chart

I need help adding a marker to this donut chart script I've modified utilizing raphael.js. I've got most everything ready to go except for a way to dynamically generate a triangular marker.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aP7MK/73/

```
function donutChart(total, goal, avg){

    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 400, 400);
    paper.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
            a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
            x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            path;
        if (total == value) {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
            ];
        } else {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
            ];
        }
        return {
            path: path
        };
    };

    var backCircle = paper.circle(100, 100, 40).attr({
        "stroke": "#7BC2E5",
            "stroke-width": 14
    });

    var theArc = paper.path().attr({
        "stroke": "#f5f5f5",
            "stroke-width": 14,
        arc: [100, 100, 0, 100, 40]
    });


    //event fired on each animation frame
    eve.on("raphael.anim.frame.*", onAnimate);

    //text in the middle
    theText = paper.text(100, 100, "0%").attr({
        "font-size": 18,
            "fill": "#f5f5f5",
            "font-weight": "bold"
    });

    //the animated arc
    theArc.rotate(0, 100, 100).animate({
        arc: [100, 100, ((total/goal) * 100), 100, 40]
    }, 1900);


    //on each animation frame we change the text in the middle

    function onAnimate() {
        var howMuch = theArc.attr("arc");
        theText.attr("text", Math.floor(howMuch[2]) + "%");
    }
}

donutChart(80, 140, 40);
```

Here's what I'm eventually trying to create:

[image]

I'm not worried about the styling, just need help with the marker element, which will denote where the avg argument being passed to the donutChart function lies within the chart.

Comment: Could you use var tri = paper.path("M100,100,130,100,100,130z"); and then rotate/translate it depending on howMuch or something ?

Comment: Hey @Ian - Sorry, I should've clarified that I don't really have any experience with generating SVGs. I found the code above within another SO question and modified it slightly to be more along the lines of what I'm looking for, but as for drawing and generating paths I have no idea where to start. Any chance you could try updating the example on fiddle with your suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ian said you can use `path` to draw triangle:

```
// triangle
var tri = paper.path("M100 50 L90 40 L110 40 L100 50 Z");
```

See the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathElement) about using `path` (its commands).

Then you need to rotate/translate (again as @Ian said) but SVG helps you here providing [`rotate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) method which takes not only angle of rotation but also coordinates of point to rotate around (it translates coordinates for you)

```
tri.rotate((howMuch[2] - prev_percent) * 3.6, 100, 100);
```

The only thing here to note is that you need difference of previous and current percentage.

The working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RS882/)

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddle!  I've made a few changes to what you set up to further mimic what I need for my final product and was wondering if you know how to color in the triangle or possibly add a straight line within the circle similar to the image above. http://jsfiddle.net/RS882/3/

Comment: It's easy http://jsfiddle.net/RS882/4/. Actually you have all the pieces in your code to figure it out

Comment: Nice! I've learned a lot about SVGs from this, thanks again for the help @twil!